# Integral extension of polynomial rings.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

If $R\subseteq S$ is an integral extension, then $R[x]\subseteq S[x]$ is an integral extension as well. Why?

$R,S$ are both commutative rings with $1$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201554/polynomial-ring-with-integral-coefficients-is-integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sums and products of integral elements are integral, and elements of $ S[x] $ are $ S $-linear combinations of powers of $ x $. Since $ S $ is integral over $ R $, and thus $ R[x] $, by assumption; and $ x $ (by virtue of being an element of $ R[x] $) is integral over $ R[x] $, it follows that any $ S $-linear combination of powers of $ x $ is also integral, and thus $ S[x] $ is an integral extension of $ R[x] $.

Comment: It was really simple. Thanks, Starfall. I was on the wrong way, trying to find a nice polynomial in $R[x][y]$, you know...